# PowerBi Service: ODBC Unable to Connect to Data Source(PostgreSQL on AWS cloud)

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, odbc

[image: ODBC Unable to connect]

Hello everyone, so I keep getting this error each time I try to refresh my dataset on power bi service. The data credential area is grayed out on powerbi service. I used ODBC to connect to PostgreSQL database hosted on AWS cloud service. Created my dashboard on desktop and publish but can't refresh on powerbi service but it refreshes on desktop. Please can anyone help resolve this?

[image: SQL query used to spool data through odbc connection]

Comment: Do you have that DSN configured on the Gateway?

Comment: I'm not so sure. How do i check that?